# Macbook Pro mid 2014 can't adjust brightness

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

My laptop:

> Macbook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)
>
> Processor 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5
>
> Memory 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
>
> Graphics Intel Iris 1536 MB
>
> OSX Mojave Version 10.14.3

My screen broke, so I bought [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/For-Apple-Macbook-Pro-13-A1706-A1708-2016-2017-Gray-LCD-Display-Screen-Assembly/264230750291?hash=item3d85614853:g:7jQAAOSwrANciBqx:sc:USPSPriority!30519!US!-1) replacement screen and fixed it myself.

Everything seems to work fine except that my brightness stays at max and won't adjust, unless I put my laptop into "sleep" mode after a reboot.

This problem has persisted since `OSX High Sierra`, so I don't think Mojave has anything to do with it.  It has also persisted across *multiple* OS re-installations.

Also note that the problem doesn't exist when using windows 10 BOOTCAMP, and seems to only happen when using OSX.

What is the cause for this bug and what can I do to troubleshoot this?  Is this a known issue?

Any advice and/or links to related topics would be appreciated!

### Edit

I am able to press the brightness keys (F1 and F2) and the small popup window shows up (shown below).  Unless I put my computer in "sleep" mode first, changing the brightness has no effect on the brightness of the computer, despite it indicating that the brightness level is changing.

[image: brightness popup]

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `F1` and `F2` to change the brightness -- does holding `Fn` and using `F1` and `F2` make any difference? Second thing to try: have a look in the App Store for a software brightness controller (e.g. [Brightness Slider](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/brightness-slider/id456624497?mt=12) - this is from a search, I have not tried it) - does that make any difference?

Comment: @PeteCooper I added an edit to my question clarifying this.  Thanks for your help.